# Make header image right part clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, href

I have a header that is full page width. That header has CSS with background image. On that image there is some text on the center and a box "Contact us" on the right side of that image drawed. How to make that button clickable (so that user clicks on it and follows a link). Preferably only right part of that header image should be clickable. Can this be made with jquery?

Hacks are welcomed.

Comment: Hi, can you please share your code.

Comment: Hi, where is code ?

Comment: Use an image map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 0):

- It seems your question is more about how to construct a navigation menu.

I would suggest you use "grid" which is built-in with css. By doing that you can build several areas in the top bar and add pictures or text. I do not recommend you to use image map since you then use positioning that will not adapt based on your device.

Below you have a base that uses grid. I have added both HTML and CSS for simplicity. If you are aiming at creating a navigation bar, you need to add text links and position it into respective area.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>

<!--CSS-->
<style>

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  100px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header-1-left header-1-mid header-1-right"
  ;
  }

  .header-1-left {grid-area: header-1-left; background-color: grey;}
  .header-1-mid {grid-area: header-1-mid; background-color: pink;}
  .header-1-right {grid-area: header-1-right; background-color: lightblue;}

</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-1-left"></div>
  <div class="header-1-mid"></div>
  <div class="header-1-right"></div>
</div>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have create it with `position: relative` for header and `position: absolute` for  element. Try this code.

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="link"></a>
</div>

.header {
    position: relative;
}
.header .link {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```